# Дискорд рекция Ботов на Вебхуки

Tags: бот, discord, webhook

Хочу сделать чтобы **Бот** добавлял реакцию на сообщение от **ВЕБхука**, но он этого не делает.

Есть какое-то решение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Боты и пользователи имеют собственные аккаунты с тегом.

Вебхук же, не относится к категории "боты", тем более, к категории "пользователи" - взаимодействие с ними не является возможным.